# Why am i getting <searchconsole.query.Report(rows=1)> instead of numbers/strs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, google-search-console, google-api-console

Working with search console api,
made it through the basics.

Now i'm stuck on splitting and arranging the data:

When trying to split, i'm getting a NaN, nothing i try works.

```
46    ((174.0, 3753.0, 0.04636290967226219, 7.816147...
47    ((93.0, 2155.0, 0.0431554524361949, 6.59025522...
48    ((176.0, 4657.0, 0.037792570324243074, 6.90251...
49    ((20.0, 1102.0, 0.018148820326678767, 7.435571...
50    ((31.0, 1133.0, 0.02736098852603707, 8.0935569...
Name: test, dtype: object
```

When trying to manipulate the data like this (and similar interactions):

```
data=source['test'].tolist() 
data
```

Its clear that the data is not really available...

```
[<searchconsole.query.Report(rows=1)>,
 <searchconsole.query.Report(rows=1)>,
 <searchconsole.query.Report(rows=1)>,
 <searchconsole.query.Report(rows=1)>,
 <searchconsole.query.Report(rows=1)>]
```

Anyone have an idea how can i interact with my data ?

Thanks.

for reference, this is the code and the program i work with:

```
account = searchconsole.authenticate(client_config='client_secrets.json', credentials='credentials.json')
webproperty = account['https://www.example.com/']

def APIsc(date,keyword):
    results=webproperty.query.range(date, days=-30).filter('query', keyword, 'contains').get()
    return results

source['test']=source.apply(lambda x: APIsc(x.date, x.keyword), axis=1)                                          

source
```

made by: https://github.com/joshcarty/google-searchconsole

Comment: Somebody ? ... Anybody ?